# Do dial locks have repeated numbers?

Tags: physical, locks, padlocks

Can dial locks, such as the one below, have repeated numbers in their combination? For example, the combination 10-39-10 has the number 10 repeated twice in it. If so how often is this the case?

[image: A dial lock]

Comment: for the first and third number, yes. for the middle number no, it needs a physical separation\ distance of about 1/8th a turn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, these locks can have repeated first and third digits, which occur about one in 10 times.  See [Samy Kamkar's page on Master locks](https://samy.pl/master/master.html) to learn more about them.

Comment: I don't see where it says these locks can have repeated first and third digits in the source you provided.

Comment: There is no mechanical reason to prevent the first and third digits being the same.  (I too have owned a Master lock with a common 1st and 3rd digit.)  The formula shows that the first and third numbers are both divisible modulo 4 with the same remainder due to the way the discs are made.